# Clarity Datagrid Headers of Columns

Tags: vmware-clarity

There is a problem with clarity datagrid headers of columns. When i use hidden columns in datagrid and hidden column is next of visible column, scroll appears under grid, but there is a lot of space. So this is so uncomfortbly view of grid.
Will this bug be fixed? What should i do now?

"@clr/angular": "^1.0.3-patch",
"@clr/icons": "^1.0.3-patch",
"@clr/ui": "^1.0.3-patch"

Comment: This is an actual bug that you have run into. I created an issue for it on github so you can track progress on the fix for it here: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/2972.

Comment: I've solved this problem with ngClass and display-none of "datagrid-column-separator", when its the last visible column of grid. But i will wait fo this bug will be fixed.